# Method 'ToString' of DateTime? has 0 parameter(s)but is invoked with 1 argument(s)

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring, nullable

My ProcessDate type is `DateTime?` when i use ToString it is showing that exception.

```
dfCalPlanDate.Text = concreteCalPlan.ProcessDate.ToString("d");
```

Thank you for your interested.

Comment: Depends where ProcessDate came from, is a field from a db query?

Comment: Try with ProcessDate.Value.ToString

Comment: @BugFinder only the type matters, not where it came from. As the OP already mentioned, it's a `DateTime?`

Answer (score 13):

Simple: [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) (and, thus, `Nullable<DateTime>`, aka `DateTime?`) does not have a method `ToString(String)`.

You probably wanted to invoke `DateTime.ToString(String)`. To do this in a null-safe way, you can use C# 6's [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) `?.`:

```
dfCalPlanDate.Text = concreteCalPlan.ProcessDate?.ToString("d");
```

which is a concise way of writing:

```
var date = concreteCalPlan.ProcessDate;
dfCalPlanDate.Text = (date == null ? null : date.Value.ToString("d"));
```

Note that this will yield `null` if `ProcessDate` is `null`. You can append the null-coalescing operator `??` if you need another result in that case:

```
dfCalPlanDate.Text = concreteCalPlan.ProcessDate?.ToString("d") ?? "no date set";
```

Comment: This will only work with **C# 6** which should be statedin your answer.

Comment: @m.rogalski C# 6 isn't "only". Besides, the answer's point is that one needs to access `Value`. Using the concise current syntax is actually a bonus

Comment: @m.rogalski: In your opinion, what should be the lowest C# version that I can assume without explicitly mentioning it?

Comment: @Heinzi It's not about what should be the lowest. But it should be stated that your solution will work only with version 6+ and not with the version when `Nullable<>` was implemented or even the version commonly used.

Comment: @m.rogalski: Thanks for your feedback, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: thank u all.
@Heinzi i am not using C# 6 so it doesnt work for me. But thank u it is good solution. it will be usefull

Answer (score 3):

ProcessDate is not a DateTime. ProcessDate.Value is. You need to do:

```
dfCalPlanDate.Text = concreteCalPlan.ProcessDate.Value.ToString("d");
```

Remember to check if the DateTime? has a value first.

Comment: if (concretePlan.ProcessDate != null) dfCalPlanDate.Text = concreteCalPlan.ProcessDate.Value.ToString("d");

it is usefull thank you.